# Appending and manipulating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see the my test site [here](http://garyryan.info/tests/bubbles.html).

The script is written in the `<head>` so you will be able to see it there.

**Instructions**

If you click the blue area a new element will be made. Do this four or five times. Now click all the elements you've just created. They should all have a black outline. However, some do and some don't.

**Additional Info:**

Only tested on chrome so far.

Any ideas on what's going wrong here?

Comment: Depending on the # of bubbles created, it adds the class only to even or odd bubbles.  Looking at the source, I think it has something to do with not setting the `active` class before you remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the click listener to *all* bubbles each time a new one is created.

Add the listener once with the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) listener. It can be set before any of the bubbles are created.

And don't use numeric `id` attributes, it's disallowed by HTML.

Also, you are toggling the `active` class -- there's a shorter function for this -- [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify using this:

```
$(function () {
  // CREATE A NEW BUBBLE

  $('.drop').click(function(event){
    Bubble(event);
  });

  var newBubbleId = 0;
  function Bubble(event,bubbleClass){
    // Create Element
    var id = newBubbleId++;
    var bubble = $('<div class="bubble" id="b_'+id+'" draggable="true"><input id="bubbleText" type="text" name="text" value="'+id+'" /></div>');
    $('body').append(bubble);

    // Position Element
    var bubbleWidth = bubble.width();
    var bubbleHeight = bubble.height();
    var x = event.pageX - (bubbleWidth*0.5);
    var y = event.pageY - (bubbleHeight*0.5);
    bubble.offset({top:y, left:x});
    bubble.click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
  }

});
```

I see a few other issues. Number ids as mentioned before.  Also, all your input elements have the same ID, that is not allowed. One ID per document only. You can use the Name attribute if you want them to have the same name.

Also, your counter function isn't ideal.

But this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, a very valid and simple solution. I know, my code's really sloppy at this point, will have a tidy up.